# How can I show this operation makes $\mathbb Q^*$ a group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Any thoughts on how to approach this would be super helpful:

If $\mathbb Q^{*}$ is a set of nonzero rational numbers. For $r,\,s\,\in\,\mathbb{Q^{*}}$, let $r\bullet s=3rs$. Show that $\mathbb Q^{*}$ under $\bullet$ is a group.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Just go through the group axioms to show they’re satisfied

Comment: Is it an associative operation?

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to go back to the definition of groups:

- Is the operation closed ?
- Is it associative ?
- What is the identity ?
- Does every rationnal (other than 0) has an inverse ?

Answer (score 1):

There’s a standard trick, or technique, in mathematics, called Transport of Structure. If $G$ is a group, or field, or whatever algebraic structure, and $\psi:G\to X$ is any bijection onto a set $X$, then you may furnish $X$ with a structure isomorphic to $G$, simply by forcing $\psi$ to *be* an isomorphism. That is, take a pair of elements $x,y\in X$, and define $x\bullet y=\psi\bigl(\psi^{-1}(x)\star\psi^{-1}(y)\bigr)$ if $\star$ is the law of composition in $G$.

You see that this trick has made $X$ into a “shadow” of $G$: you have taken your $x,y$ and seen where they came from in $G$, multiplied those preimages to get a product in $G$, and then carried that product back to $X$.

I think you’ll see that your $\psi$ will have to be multiplication by an appropriate nonzero rational number. You find it.